# Python API: Changing the order of shapekeys quickly

Tags: python, shape-keys

Using the Python API, is there a way to change order of shapekeys quicker than using the operator `bpy.ops.object.shape_key_move(type='UP')`?

This operator takes a long time to execute (if you want to move a shape key up 20 times, for example).

Is there a way to perform this quicker?

Answer (score 2):

Campbell said me on IRC that there is currently no other solution :

> this needs to be done at a C/RNA level AFAICS.
>
> RNA collections need to have a sort callback which Python can use